# Embedding a form and posting it to another site

Tags: javascript, php, html

Had a question around forms and posting data to other web sites. The website in question has a donation form I would like to utilize - and they are serving as a fiscal sponsor for a company I work for. Currently we have to link to their form and guide our users on how to donate through them. I want to embed their form on our site so as to skip the step of linking to their form and make it easier on our users.

I first started with simply copying their forms' HTML verbatim but when I click the submit button to submit a donation, it takes me to their "cart" page and there is nothing in the cart.

So I'm not sure what else to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *cart* refers to an object in session. Simply copying the HTML will not enable the add to cart of other site.

In this case must redirect the user to other site. Or you can use an *iframe* for embedding the other page in your site.

Comment: Thanks - I'd love to learn more about how this works. Do you have any suggestions on materials?

Comment: you may refer to this document for information on iframes https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: Cool, thanks. Out of curiosity, if I was in contact of the site owner with the cart, could I build something that embedded their form and was able to add items across sites?

Comment: Awesome. What would that involve? Not expecting you to answer but would be grateful if you could point me in the direction of what to learn? THanks :)